# conditional probability formula

Tags: probability

> A family is being asked three questions:
>
> 1. How many people are you? ($N$ r.v)
> 2. Was there a birthday yesterday? ($A$ r.v)
> 3. How many days in year, at least one family member has a birthday ($K$ r.v)
>
> Find $P(K=1|N=2,A)$.

Now, the answer starts with:

$$P(K=1|N=2,A) = \frac{P(K=1, A|N=2)}{P(A|N=2)}$$

Could you explain what was done here? I can't recall a theorem which supports this.

Answer (score 1):

Bayes' theorem is essentially $P(B\mid A) = \dfrac{P(B, A)}{P(A)}$ so long as the denominator is non-zero

and this can all be conditioned on some other event as in  $P(B\mid C, A) = \dfrac{P(A, B \mid C)}{P(A\ \mid C)}$

which is your expression when the event $B$ is $K=1$ and the event $C$ is $N=2$.

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you explain the transition from the first equation to the second one please?

Comment: Shouldn't we treat $C,A$ as one variable and then apply the first equation?

Comment: The first and the second are essentially the same, except that the second restricts the sample space to when the event $C$ occurs.